# case/type sensitivity in msbuild conditions

Tags: msbuild

**Preamble**

After running some build scripts of my own on some other machine I discovered they were not working because `svn` tools were not installed and because of some  of my conditions on `MSBuildLastTaskResult` property were incorrect (was using capital letters inside the condition).

**Problem**

Here what I don't understand is that conditions for some properties are case-insensitive and for other they are case-sensitive. Look at below example:

```
<Project DefaultTargets="Test" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">

    <PropertyGroup>
        <MyProperty>FOoBAR</MyProperty>
    </PropertyGroup>

    <Target Name="Test">

        <!-- Making sure `MSBuildLastTaskResult` will return `false` -->
        <Copy SourceFiles="Does.Not.Exists" ContinueOnError="true"/>

        <!-- Testing `MSBuildLastTaskResult` -->
        <Message Text="Hello" Importance="high" Condition="'$(MSBuildLastTaskResult)' == 'false'" />
        <Message Text="World" Importance="high" Condition="'$(MSBuildLastTaskResult)' == 'False'" />

        <!-- Testing `MyProperty` -->
        <Message Text="ALL CAPS" Importance="high" Condition="'$(MyProperty)' == 'FOOBAR'" />
        <Message Text="all lower" Importance="high" Condition="'$(MyProperty)' == 'foobar'" />

    </Target>

</Project>
```

It will display in the console:

```
Hello
ALL CAPS
all lower
```

So it appears condition on `MyProperty` is not case-sensitive while condition on `MSBuildLastTaskResult` is (~ ? or may be includes for further type checking ? ~).

I'm a bit confused here. How/when msbuild is making decisions to do case/type detection when comparing properties ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MsBuild *is* case-insensitive here, the problem is in the second message task `MSBuildLastTaskResult` is in fact the result of the previous task called, which in this is the first Message task and not the Copy task anymore. Easy to see if you swap the two Message lines like

```
<Message Text="World" Importance="high" Condition="'$(MSBuildLastTaskResult)' == 'FaLse'" />
<Message Text="Hello" Importance="high" Condition="'$(MSBuildLastTaskResult)' == 'false'" />
```

the output will be

```
World
ALL CAPS
all lower
```

Comment: Oops ... indeed! I will better review my build scripts to see what was really wrong even if fixed now.